# MYSQL (xampp on ubuntu) crashing XAMPP 8.0.13-1

Tags: mysql

I have changing column collection from utf8_general_ci to utf8mb4_general_ci after I save change the system had been stop and cann't start. I found in err log msg like these.

[ERROR] InnoDB: Corruption of an index tree: table `vporder`.`orders_log` index `BUYER`, father ptr page no 7259, child page no 7265

some bodyknow, how i can fix or get the data from these problem

Comment: Is this error message complete? Can you access the content at father ptr page no 7259, child page no 7265 (that tuple in the data)?

Comment: not yet. mysql cann't start.